# How to use the calendar

Tags: calendar

I know that there is a calendar in Emacs and I want to use it. After a lot of Google searches, and also after reading Emacs' manual, I still have no idea how to use it. The only thing I have succeeded is to view a buffer with 3 months.

What I want to do is use it like the Google Calendar so to be able to write entries in the days I want and some notes.

I have seen that there are also some other options available like the diary but the only thing I have find for it is a description so I don't actually know what it is! How can someone use Emacs as a Calendar and what are the options to do so (Calendar, Diary etc)?

Comment: You may be interested in synchronizing your calendar with Toodledo so that all your mobile / desktop devices have access to the same database:  https://github.com/christopherjwhite/org-toodledo  If you find that you enjoy `elisp` / customizing Emacs, then little by little you can have a fully functional calendar that will display birthdays, holidays, meetings, etc. in the form of multicolored entries on the calendar and a corresponding org-agenda buffer with details in the other window.  I use both a 12-month (large screen) and a 3-month calendar (small screen) to display my entries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're looking for a Google calendar like tool built into Emacs, take a look at [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/).  To set up, just add

```
(require 'org)
(define-key global-map "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
```

to your `.emacs`.  You can then create a file called (for example) `calendar.org` containing lines like

```
* An Event
  <2014-12-18>
* TODO A Task
  SCHEDULED: <2014-12-19>
* This takes a week
  <2014-12-14>-<2014-12-20>
```

You can then add this file to `org-agenda-files` and use `org-agenda` to view a weeks worth of events (the most common binding for this is `C-c a a`).  There can be as many or as few of these files as you like.

`org-mode` can keep an agenda, a todo list, capture notes, events and tasks from other files and export it all into a variety of formats (including icalendar, which can be imported by most other calendaring tools).

It's quite complex at first but pretty easy once you get used to it.  The [tutorial](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/orgtutorial_dto.html) will help you get started.

Answer (score 16):

You ask a very general question about using this feature and how to find a detailed description of it, what its possibilities are, and how they work.

The answer is to **ask Emacs**. Use **`C-h r`** to consult the Emacs manual. Then use **`i calendar RET`** to go to node `Calendar/Diary`, which is a subsection of the manual that has several subsubsections:

```
* Calendar Motion::     Moving through the calendar; selecting a date.
* Scroll Calendar::     Bringing earlier or later months onto the screen.
* Counting Days::       How many days are there between two dates?
* General Calendar::    Exiting or recomputing the calendar.
* Writing Calendar Files:: Writing calendars to files of various formats.
* Holidays::            Displaying dates of holidays.
* Sunrise/Sunset::      Displaying local times of sunrise and sunset.
* Lunar Phases::        Displaying phases of the moon.
* Other Calendars::     Converting dates to other calendar systems.
* Diary::               Displaying events from your diary.
* Appointments::        Reminders when it's time to do something.
* Importing Diary::     Converting diary events to/from other formats.
* Daylight Saving::     How to specify when daylight saving time is active.
* Time Intervals::      Keeping track of time intervals.
* Advanced Calendar/Diary Usage:: Advanced Calendar/Diary customization.
```

Then start reading about whatever you want to know about using the calendary and diary.

Comment: Calenday Motion doesnt actually appear to tell you how to select a date. Do you know how?